# WPF+MVVM+EF Реализация Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-core

Всем добрового времени суток. У меня есть несколько вопросов в плане WPF+MVVM+EFcore. Имеется база на PostgreSQL поэтому подход идет DatabaseFirst в которой больше 20 таблиц:

1. Как правильно должна быть реализована Model-ь? Должна ли в ней быть реализация загрузки данных, добавление/удаление /редактирование данных из БД?
2. В подходе DatabeseFirst EF создает классы сущности, являются ли они Model или считаются контекстом данных?

Хотелось бы получить не только простой ответ, а так же советы что можно было бы почитать, изучить и различные примеры. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Anemic vs rich model - это старый холивар. Можно делать по-разному. Однако, EF использует бедные модели - они сами ничего не умеют, их сохраняет в БД контекст.

Comment: Клиентские приложения не используют прямой доступ в БД в случае многопользовательской реализации. Так что ваша комбинация WPF и EF является нетипичной и фантастичной для практического использования. Для доступа в БД используют сервер, а для клиента открывают наружу API этого самого сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model в MVVM - это объектная модель данных, напрямую связанная с источником данных, находящимся за пределами приложения.

Все что требуется от модели - это обеспечение связи вьюмоделей с источником данных. Что именно реализовано внутри модели и что какие сервисы она будет предоставлять VM, на уровне MVVM не имеет значения. Это имеет значение на уровне требований к приложению. Например мне достаточно однократно загрузить данные из Web API, то у меня модель неизменяемая и мне не требуется уведомлять VM об обновлениях данных. Если у вас требуется двухсторонняя синхронизация с источником данных, то потребуются дополнительные интерфейсы с колбэками или событиями, чтобы VM смогли на них подписываться, в этом, собственно основная разница и заключается, и EF здесь совершенно не при чем.

Единственное, что здесь имеет значение на уровне MVVM - это наличие слабой связи в трехслойной архитектуре приложения. Если конкретно, то например вы реализовали EF+БД в модели, потом хорошенько подумали и решили унести EF на сервер и вместо этого реализовать работу с API сервера, например на базе gRPC.

Так вот, правильно реализованный MVVM позволит вам подменить одно содержимое Model на другое не ломая остальные части приложения. Практически то же самое, как если бы вы решили заменить View например с WPF на WinUI 3. В этом и есть смысл MVVM - максимальная независимость между тремя слоями.